# Is it all right to flag very new answer as 'very low quality'?

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts, fastest-gun, grace-period

From time to time I look at new questions where people just 'throw in' near empty answers to be first. These answers sometimes just contain the first line of the real answer or just a single line of code (non-highlighted to prevent the system from complaining).

Now, my automatic reaction is to just flag these as very low quality, but then a minute later they get updated with proper content. What should I do?

Comment: [fastest gun in the west](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Comment: I think I read a very similar question already, but can't find it... However, yes this is alright. If a user posts an answer he/she says this a a complete, correct answer. If it is not, then flag it. If it gets edited later, that is neither your fault nor your responsibility.

Comment: keep flagging if it happens infrequently and you feel strong enough to survive couple occasional disputes/declines. Otherwise, make a habit to wait until [grace-period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grace-period) ends prior to flagging

Comment: [Give Shog some examples](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168295/206447). This could be a clear case of abuse, **assuming the first revision is sufficiently low quality or non-answering** (I'm sure the first revision is stored somewhere - not doing so would be... stupid?, so he should have something to look at if you just point him to a post).

Answer (score 32):

Your flag should be cast based on the state of the answer at the time that you see it, rather than on potential future improvements. The person answering the question has clicked the "Post Your Answer" button and should expect to be judged on answer as posted. If an answer doesn't meet the quality standards, and if you plan to browse away from the question, go ahead and raise the flag. The reviewers will be able to make their own judgments about the quality of the answer when they conduct their reviews.

The alternative is to wait around for the answerer to update the answer with useful information. If you plan to do so, there's nothing wrong with waiting to flag, but you should not feel obligated to wait.

Comment: Related: [Make first draft of a new answer part of the permanent revision history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138017/165773)

Comment: The 'problem' (for lack of a better word) is that the reviewers get to see an answer that's written out nicely and looks fine.

Comment: Since the number/rate of declined flags does influence how many flags you can use per day, what you suggest can have a very negative impact for people that act this way often. Maybe downvoting (to signal that the current state isn't acceptable) and going back 5 minutes later to see if a flag should be used is a better option.

Comment: @DavidMulder They do, and if the answer has been updated to meet standards, the flag will be declined. Is that a problem?

Comment: @Bakuriu If you plan to come back in five minutes, then there is nothing wrong with simply waiting (I addressed that in the answer) or downvoting if you feel the need. However, given the number of questions posted to the site on a regular basis, and the fact that we simply _don't know_ whether a particular answerer plans to make changes to a posted answer, that cannot be the most common approach.

Comment: I meant that I'd follow the "opposite philosophy": if you don't have time to decide whether to flag or not: *don't*. If you do it incorrectly you are going to waste the time of a few reviewers. However a downvote can be a safer alternative that achieve about the same effect. If an answer get a few downvotes the answerer will probably improve it/delete it or somebody else may notice the really poor quality after some minutes and flag it.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins: 1) time of the reviewers is wasted and 2) statistics regarding flags are kept.

Comment: @DavidMulder The flag statistics are stored, but never used for anything except feedback for you as a flagger, so it's not like you need to be concerned, so long as you're not intentionally abusing the system.

Comment: (Apparently) little-known fact: edits to a post flagged as Very Low Quality will immediately dismiss that flag as helpful. So you really don't have to worry about flagging a post that's abysmally bad *now* - if it gets fixed before it gets into review, your flag will silently go away. @David

Comment: @Shog9 if edit happened after the flag but during grace period, can system distinguish that as a flag-validating edit?

Comment: It *could*, @gnat, but it currently *doesn't.* (went and tested this to make sure)

Comment: @Shog9 in that case, your comment looks irrelevant to the situation discussed here: per my reading, OP asked about flagging fastest-gun (crappy) "drafts" that are typically overwritten during grace period -- _"my automatic reaction is to just flag these as very low quality, but then a minute later they get updated with proper content."_ Side note how come you are behind me in [MSO participation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=participation)? :)

Comment: @Shog9 FWIW I submitted a feature request to **[Recognize edits that happened after the VLQ flag but during grace period as flag-validating ones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231199/165773 "here")**

Answer (score 11):

As far as I can tell, **[recent changes to the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251876/165773)** send a fairly strong message on what is expected of you. When you see an answer that looks incomplete, first thing to consider is asking to clarify this in comments. Like this:

> **this answer looks incomplete, why?**

From there, feel free to proceed as you prefer.

If you wish, wait for incompleteness to be clarified, either in comments or by next post edit.

Note that changes made by post author *after your comment* will now be clearly visible as a separate edit entry in post [revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/revision-history/info). By the way, if you pick this approach and you notice that further edits rendered your question obsolete, consider deleting your comment to avoid confusing readers.

Of course, you can also vote down and flag the post, if you're not inclined to wait or do not expect it to be improved.

If you choose to do so, it is important to remember that because of mentioned system change, in case if author improves the post, there will be a new post revision *after your comment* so that you will be able to retract downvote if it is sufficiently improved. Similarly for VLQ/NAA flags, new post revision will [automatically dismiss these as helpful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252854/165773).

Comment: frankly, this new feature to trigger saving current revision after comment may eventually make all this fastest-gun game much less appealing than it is now. No matter how fast answerer is, commenters can be _even faster_... and they aren't bound by the necessity to edit their stuff into better shape, as opposed to what one has to do with "draft answers"

Answer (score 3):

A custom flag explaining the initial low quality answer (**assuming the first revision is sufficiently low quality or non-answering**) which was posted essentially as just a placeholder to be first?

Although a moderator should probably tell us if they'd actually do something about that ... and whether they actually have access to the first revision (if they don't, they really should).

---

You could consider downvoting it.

There are plenty of reasons to downvote, and I'm sure a valid one is:

> I don't approve of this type of behaviour (assuming the behaviour is specific to the post).

Or you could even argue the official:

> This answer is not useful.

Which could be true, **at the time of posting / voting**, regardless of whether it's true later on.

If such users get sufficiently many downvotes because of this, the reputation cost of this will hopefully outweigh the cost of taking another minute or two to post a decent answer.

---

Keep in mind that a short:

> The problem is ...

Answer can still answer the question and be somewhat useful (and probably not worthy of a downvote or custom flag).

Comment: But when the answerer completes the answer (within the grace period, with no history) you might have a good answer, which doesn't deserve a downvote: that's likely to attract sympathy upvotes and/or legit ones, making your downvote useless and too costly (and, technically, incorrect). If you retract it, you're showing you were not serious in your "punishment" and you give the poster more rep. It's not an easy conundrum

Comment: @DamienPirsy Fair enough. If you're feeling brave, you could always post a comment stating the reason for the downvote.