# Answering questions briefly to be first and then editing to lengthen it

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, fastest-gun, grace-period

Not that I have an issue with this, on principle, It is helpful to build on your answer and provide more content.

However, when I am answering questions and I am building up an answer and come across a person who just fills in one line then to make sure their answer **gets on the board first** and then **continuously keeps editing** it, I find that mildly annoying.

Additionally, if you provide a **brief answer** and the answer ahead of you is heavily detailed (the first version just had a sentence), your answer even seems to attract a few down votes.

Guessing there is no easy solution, one idea I can think of is that **if a person adds a short answer, you could prompt asking if they would rather make it a comment.**

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Comment: Also: [What is FGITW and SCITE on MSO?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18014/146015)

Comment: FYI, dropping a quick answer and then editing it to add more content **is allowed**, and is done often, especially on low-quality questions with lots of competition and easy answers. If you don't want to deal with the competition, then consider not answering those kinds of questions. I don't. It's neither fun nor interesting.

Comment: @gnat that's the solution, just flag short answers as comments? That doesn't sound like what we're supposed to do...

Comment: @Cupcake http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253865/839601 (in brief, flag only if you're ready and willing to accept the risk of SE team preference to [cover fastest gun crap drafts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231199/recognize-edits-that-happened-after-the-vlq-flag-but-during-grace-period-as-flag). Otherwise, abstain or wait until grace period expiry)

Comment: Also the time stamp of the answer could be important for Fastest-Gun-people. It just shows the first edit which could be anything. Maybe better take the average of all edits as long as they are within the first 5 minutes.