# How should I deal with claims that my answer is plagiarism of another?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, grace-period, fastest-gun

In today's fast-moving world, many answers are provided within seconds and under 5 minutes. This is especially the case for 1-line answers.

I've recently come across some aggressive behaviour, albeit in limited circumstances. Someone posts a 1-line answer (to make sure he can take ownership of this answer, fair enough) and over the next few minutes pads it out with detail and explanation.

So far so good. But another guy might be happily typing along, looking to provide the answer and explanation in one go. He posts a reasonable answer and is looking to add more information. But, lo and behold, before he can click update his answer *has been edited by the other responder* with a reference to his identical solution and an accusation that his answer was copied.

I don't expect there to be a proper solution to this, but is it too much to expect mutual respect among volunteers? [I hope responders *are* all volunteers; but the aggression seems to suggest otherwise.]

The focus of my question is on the tactic of editing within a short (< 5 minutes) span of time with a reference to your own answer and adding a comment or edit accusing the poster of plagiarism. I only mention the situation of fast answering / updating to provide context.

No question, to my knowledge, addresses the accusatory behavior particularly.

Comment: "But, lo and behold, before he can click post his answer has been edited by the other responder" - it's unclear what you mean by this. If user X hasn't yet posted their answer, it's impossible for someone else to edit it.

Comment: If somebody edits another person's answer with accusations of plagiarism, that is absolutely something with a proper solution: Rollback the edit and flag it for a moderator. That's not what edits are for.

Comment: I assume he means the original one line answer.

Comment: _is it too much to expect mutual respect among volunteers?_ On the internet? Why yes, yes it is too much too expect :)

Comment: I've updated to clarify. Maybe one user's answer was 5 lines and the other was 1 line. The 5 line answerer wants to add more detail / perhaps an example. All this is within the space of 2 minutes.

Comment: I am guessing you mean the person A starts editing continuosly _within the grace period_?

Comment: I think you need more editing - "looking to provide the answer and explanation in one go" doesn't sound like what the second user is really doing here...

Comment: He may be fixing a typo, after he's submitted. The relevant point is in less than 5 minutes his answer is being edited with false accusations "you copied my answer" being added in comments.

Comment: Honestly ... My experience is that this only happens on very basic questions. They will be answered within minutes, or seconds even, as they are easily answerable with a one liner. They should probably be closed as a duplicate of something, but they are all unique little snowflakes of course. Anyway. Solution: avoid those questions. Look at questions that have not been answered for at least, say, 12 hours.

Comment: And yes, I have answered those questions in the past. I have been bitten by copying users. Lesson learned.

Comment: @Justastudent, what's basic to you might not be basic to someone else. What's more, just because a solution is short it does not mean it is of lower quality / necessarily a duplicate. Often it's oversimplified, or poorly (or not at all) explained.

Comment: Closely related: [Is it a bad practice to post a short answer first and then add details afterwards?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303446/is-it-bad-practice-to-post-a-short-answer-first-and-then-add-details-afterwards?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254811/answering-questions-briefly-to-be-first-and-then-editing-to-lengthen-it?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: even worse: FFGITW posts wrong answer, gets 1 downvote, deletes, another answer arrives in the meanwhile (correct), then wrong deleted answer is edited with the same contents as the second answer. Grace period makes it look like second answer copied the first one, whereas it may be the other way round.

Comment: I think people are missing the main point: editing other people's answers within 5 minutes. Is this normal, expected, *encouraged*? Especially if the only point is to try to transfer credibility.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I don't think I've seen the practice of editing other people's answers to reference your own FGITW answer documented at all.

Comment: @jpp Editing other people's answer is fine. Editing to say "look at my other FGITW answer" is not.

Comment: FGITW - known problems. Idea: Hide the answers for some time (say, 1 hour) after the question had been posted.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre In this case, flag seems appropriate. Copying others' answer is cheating.

Comment: @user202729 That does nothing to remove the problem, and causes a while bunch more problems (namely that people take an extra hour to get their answer, and *tons* of duplicate answers will be posted by people not realizing the post had already been answered).

Comment: @Servy About the former - not a problem. (["helping the OP is a secondary goal"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question#comment503692_284486)) The latter is indeed a problem. /// The problem only exists for easy questions, which is most certainly a dupe of something.

Comment: @user202729 It doesn't just hurt the OP, it hurts *everyone* looking for an answer, which is of course the primary goal.  And it accomplishes *nothing*, it just makes everything objectively worse.  And that's not even getting into the fact that delaying showing answers for an hour completely kills the whole feedback loop.  People seeing the new question, or the OP, won't be able to give feedback on answers right away, and if/when they *do* get feedback in an hour the author may not then be around to see it for quite some time, all greatly harmering the ability of answers to be improved.

Comment: @user202729 No, the problem *doesn't* just exist for easy questions.  There are plenty of expert programmers that are even able to answer extremely complicated answers quite quickly.  You'll find cases where two or three extremely skilled programmers will all answer a question at the same time, even if the majority of programmers (even those following the tag(s) in question) wouldn't be able to answer it.  Additionally, lots of easy questions aren't duplicates.  It's super easy to have a trivially easy problem, but ensure it's sufficiently localized that it isn't a duplicate of anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it bad practice to post a short answer first and then add details afterwards?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303446/is-it-bad-practice-to-post-a-short-answer-first-and-then-add-details-afterwards)

Comment: Mutual respect? Lets aim for co-existence, where possible with the least amount of friction :)

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: [Placeholder Answers: Will update with answer soon!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269993/2564301)

Comment: jump up and down and scream loudly

Comment: Pistols at dawn.

Comment: In general, if the question is such that it can be answered within seconds or in a single line, chances are very high that it is a duplicate. In such case, better look for the duplicate and vote to close instead of getting into some first-to-answer-war. Only because some people like to play this game, you do the community a much higher favor by closing duplicate questions or answer those questions which are harder to solve. Naturally this will limit the amount of unicorn points you get, but mind that true reputation is earned by taking the right decisions and providing high-quality help.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre "...Grace period makes it look like second answer copied the first one, whereas it may be the other way round." Very good point. I will immediately start waiting for correct answers to be posted and simply duplicate them (slightly changing them). That way I'll get rep without end.

Comment: I happen to know what user you're speaking about, because it's happened to me as well. The best solution is to not be active in the tag during those timezones ;)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

As meagar has stated, if someone is using an edit to accuse a competing answer of plagiarism, that's inappropriate and the edit should be rolled back.

As Andy has stated, if someone is intrusively editing a competing answer to replace some or all of its content with a link to their own answer, regardless of whether they have evidence of plagiarism, that constitutes vandalism and the edit should be rolled back.

If a user believes in good faith that another user has plagiarized their answer (in an answer to either the same question or a different one), they should report it with a flag and let a moderator handle it. Never mind that public accusations in comments are strongly discouraged — *editing* the allegedly offending answer is, as you've described, aggressive and will just make you look bad if it turns out that your answer was in fact not plagiarized (which is almost always the case when we're talking about answers posted seconds or minutes apart). All this on top of being an abuse of the edit function.

Only moderators and staff may be sanctioned to edit or delete answers to sanitize copied content, and we have a policy never to do it ourselves in situations where we answered the same question or otherwise have a personal stake — we'll even go through the same channels as regular users do, flagging for another moderator to make an impartial decision.

Comment: You should add that after flagging it as moderator, there might be a delay of (almost) longer than a week before a moderator sees it and reverts it, not everyone expects such long delay (source: my still pending moderator flag)

Comment: @Ferrybig: You can roll back the offending edits yourself in the meantime. The moderator's job is to figure out if the offending user needs a talking-to. Besides, I assumed most people reading this would be aware of the other thread about how long flags were taking to be handled already.

Answer (score 0):

A question needs only one copy of the same correct answer - both for the original poster and for future visitors. If someone posts an answer that duplicates an existing one, even if it's three seconds later, it seems to me that the author of the second answer should delete it. What purpose does it serve, other than perhaps to collect a few votes for its author? How does an identical or almost identical answer help anyone? This is regardless of anyone's accusation of plagiarism. You post an answer, you look and see that someone else beat you to it, delete your own - not because you may be accused of plagiarism, but because it adds nothing to the usefulness of the thread.

This is the problem with reputation systems: on the one hand SO pretends like the purpose of the site is to help people find answers to their questions, but then they create perverse incentives with the reputation system. (On the other hand, obviously, a lot of experienced people who provide answers here are clearly motivated by the reputation thing; I don't blame SO for taking this approach to attract many experts here, we just need to recognize what is going on and either accept it or give up on SO.)

This is quite different from two related questions. (1) If you post an answer where, in addition to what the other poster already said, you also explain how something works, or state under what assumptions it will work (pointing out that there will be cases when it doesn't), etc., then you are adding value; let someone else accuse you of plagiarism, but if they edit your post that's vandalism and it should be reported. (2) If, for example, you do something like I described in (1) and then some jerk copies what you wrote and adds it to THEIR answer, which they posted ten seconds before you - but it is within the grace period for editing - then report them to the moderators and let them deal with it.

I don't know - there is a grace period for what we, mere mortals, see on our screens. Doesn't the system, though, keep an accurate record of ACTUAL timestamps when each action occurred? If so, it should be easy for a moderator to see what really happened, even if you or I do not have access to that information.

Comment: This post highlights one point. An answer is often a combination of code plus explanation. Some users believe an answer is just code. [It behoves such rep-builders to *not* give explanations, as this yields more rep-earning questions.] In my example, the second but not necessarily the first responder provides explanation. Certainly, the purpose of edits / comments is not to get into a timestamp war. Related: [How to handle equivalent answers but different explanations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364079/how-to-handle-equivalent-answers-but-different-explanations).

Comment: "...it seems to me that the author of the second answer should delete it." Often enough it's done this way, but there is no obligation. If the answer creator decides to leave it, he/she can leave it there of course. One answer could still be slightly better than the other.

Comment: In addition to what @jpp said: 1) It's *vanishingly unlikely* for two users to post identical code+explanation answers in a small window of time (it's only ever happened to me [exactly once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43685170/adding-a-class-to-a-psuedo-before-element#comment74416708_43685265) in the 7+ years I've been active on the site) 2) Should someone posting a code-only answer be unlucky enough to receive downvotes from people who dislike such answers, rather than upvotes from people who like them, they tend to delete their answer in response.

Answer (score -9):

I think people are going overboard with the plagiarism with answers. Mainly because certain sciences, like computers and electronics are so technical they can't be explained or rephrased in any other way. I got dinged in the electronics form because what I said was almost verbatim across thousands of web pages when the plagiarism troll attacked me. This is not English class. Its science. So, how many times can Ohm's Law or kirchoff's Law can be rephrased before you can't rephrase it (for example)?

Comment: Hmm, your observation isn't much related to the question, interesting as it is. Maybe it should be a comment.