# How to handle equivalent answers but different explanations

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

**Background**

Sometimes, especially with [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), there is a solution which correctly completes OP's proposed task, but misses the bigger picture.

Here is one example:
[Why does the format change when converting DatetimeIndex to np.array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49083524/why-does-the-format-change-when-converting-datetimeindex-to-np-array/49084003?noredirect=1#comment85173853_49084003)

A trivial solution, `dict(zip(idx, lst))`, was accepted after some useful commentary, i.e. don't convert your `datetime` objects to `str` when it's not necessary.

**Scenario**

One user started by answering the question as stated, but then after the comments (proposal by another user) started writing up the obvious "XY solution". Within 1 minute of each other, both users post identical solutions *in code terms*. User1's XY solution ends up half way through the answer as an Edit, User2's begins and ends with the XY solution.

User2 is accused of plagiarism and flags his answer (which includes inappropriate comments) to a moderator. He doesn't want to waste time challenging the accusations in comments, nor does he want to waste time checking the timestamps on his posts.

But User2 still thinks his post is more clearly explained than the other.

**Question**

At what point are 2 solutions equivalent, and one should be deleted? Here, in my mind, it's clearly a case of explanation, rather than code. Hence the 2 solutions are distinct.

This is a small example, and very specific, but I believe it is often the case that clarity on the problem and data structure / framework / workflow offers a trivial solution, and 20 characters of code should not be deemed to be plagiarisable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are right. Two answers with distinct and original presentations of what happens to be the same idea are allowed to coexist. Neither of them is subject to deletion on this basis alone, *except* when one of them is both low-effort **and** several months or years late.

If the low-effort answer was posted at around the same time as the other answer, it may be downvoted or simply not voted on for any reason, but it's not subject to deletion, regardless of whether it was posted first. And the better answer is equally allowed to exist, even if it took longer to post by virtue of requiring more time and effort to put together.