# Cannot change vote even though the post has been edited

Tags: feature-request, edits, voting, grace-period, locked-votes

I know there is a rule on SO where you cannot change your vote after a specific period of time (I forget how long exactly, 5, 10, or 15 mins). However, you can change it if an edit has been made *after* you voted.

Well, I just down voted a question because it didn't show any attempt at solving the problem. I then commented to say the OP should attempt something, and then the OP edited the question to include attempted code. However, they must have made this edit within the 'edit grace period' (5 mins.. I think) so it doesn't show as an 'official' edit. I then tried to remove my downvote but I am not allowed:

> You last voted on this question X mins ago. Your vote is now locked
>   in unless this question is edited.

Surely this would make more sense to allow a re-vote after a grace edit. I should be able to remove my downvote as the question is now more acceptable (in my opinion) and I don't think it deserves my downvote.

I know I could work around the issue by forcing my own edit, but I don't feel that is an acceptable solution going forward.

For those interested, [this is the question in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930393/how-to-clear-google-map-history-on-button-click-android)

Comment: Sounds like a bug, though of course there's the trivial workaround of making an extra edit just to allow changing vote. Seems totoally justified in this case.

Comment: Grace period edits do not unlock the vote.  You should change this to a feature request

Comment: I'd say this is not a missing feature, this is a bug in a corner case of existing feature of changing vote when post has been changed after voting.

Comment: @psubsee2003: but is this by design (feature request) or should it be the working already (bug fix)?

Comment: @hyde: I see your point, it's not hard to work around the issue, but I would prefer not to have to do a meaningless edit. Also, I may be recalling incorrectly, but it there not a 'minimum change' requirement when editing? So I would have to make a significant edit just for the sake of it?

Comment: sorry for destroying the revision history there.... I thought the rollback was just going to merge into an empty edit :( I'm pretty sure if you edit something in, and then edit it out again it gets merged into a blank edit though. - still, hardly a recommended practice

Comment: @musefan I would say is it is a consequence of the design, which is why I wouldn't call it a bug.  With the current design, the new edit revision is the trigger to unlock the votes, but since no edit revision is created, there is no trigger, and hence the votes are not unlocked.  [This has been discussed previously on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150002/quick-edit-not-recorded-as-such-blocking-vote-change) and marked as [meta-tag:status-bydesign].

Comment: @psubsee2003: Ah, good find, I still haven't gotten around to working out what has happened to meta. I know somethings changed...

Comment: this looks like one of the rare cases when [invisible edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180564/165773) seems to be justified

Comment: Well, it's your choice here. You can modify this into a feature request or I can add the status-bydesign tag for you. :)

Comment: @animuson: Done... have your 'status-declined' stamp at the ready! :)

Comment: Just ran into this myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changes introduced to the system in March 2015 addressed the issue described here.

As of now, it would be possible to retract / revert a vote in cases when edit to the post happens after voter (or "anyone *other than* the editor") commented, see [Reset question grace period once an answer has been posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251876/165773):

> Edits will be rolled into the previous revision if the previous revision was created by the same author and *none* of the following conditions are present:
>
> - The previous revision was created 5 minutes or more in the past
> - A comment has been added to the post since the previous revision by anyone *other than* the editor.
> - An answer has been added to the post since the previous revision
> - The previous revision was a rollback
> - The new revision is a rollback...

<sub>It is worth keeping in mind that votes cast without comments would still stuck if later edits are done within grace period.</sub>

---

See also: [Is it all right to flag very new answer as 'very low quality'?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289668/839601)

> recent changes to the system send a fairly strong message on what is expected of you... first thing to consider is asking to clarify this in comments...

Comment: hmmm... this doesn't seem to address the issue at all. I get what you are saying that if I comment along with my downvote then I will later be able to retract if an edit happens because it will force it to be a proper edit (not grace). But we have had discussion on meta, and even a feature for restricting comments, that encourages us **not** to leave comments explaining our downvotes... so would I be left hoping that someone else performs an action that nullifies the grace period at about the same time I downvote?

Comment: @musefan agree that this doesn't address the underlying issue. My understanding of your question is, you expected (I think quite reasonably) that edits after plain vote would make it unlock. However, the precise description of this particular case involves "I then commented" - that's why I had to answer pointing out that system changed so that this particular scenario unlocks the vote. As for the feature related to comments when downvoting, [my reading of it is, these aren't really discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285253/839601)...

Comment: ...that feature seem to only discourage opening "-1" at brief comments. To me personally it's as if it doesn't change things at all. I dropped writing stuff like "-1" or "I voted down/up" long time ago, after I realised that only me and Stack Exchange developers can tell whether this is true or lies. I prefer to focus on more tangible things when commenting

Comment: Yeah, but also consider a post quickly gets 5 downvotes, do we really want 5 comments with users saying a very similar thing, just so they can reserve the right to retract their vote in the rare event that a question is 'fixed' via edit within the grace period. I mean, what you have explained already is certainly an improvement, but it doesn't full resolve the issue

Comment: @musefan well, if I (the voter) see someone else's ("other than the editor") comment with timestamp link saying "15 secs ago", I can fairly safely assume that edits after this comment will make a new revision, so that I don't need to add mine. Though, frankly, thinking of 5 "why it's incomplete" comments dropped under crappy fastest-gun draft makes me smile

Comment: Ah ok, so as long as one person comments then all votes will be saved! I think that probably good enough to be honest...