# What is the best way to remove locked anonymous down vote?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, grace-period

Sometimes I cast down votes to certain answers with low quality contents, without a comment which describes it, and i believe that this kind of votes are called as anonymous down votes.

Now in this context, most of the answers would get deleted by their owners itself, but some of the answer posters invest their efforts additionally in order to convert their post (down voted answers) to a valid one, meaning it deserves an up vote, during the grace time for editing. At this situation, lot of times my down vote got locked into that post (valid ones) due to the time constraint that we have in SO.

Now the only way is to toggle that down vote is to make a fake edit to that post and then up vote it. But I feel guilty while doing like that and it also seems like abusing the system.

Does anybody have a genuine solution to tackle this kind of situation?

Comment: Fake edit to change your vote is a valid approach (may not be the best). Let me find the reference in the meanwhile

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me, edits during the grace period should unlock votes.

Comment: What's the relevance of the anonymity? Are you concerned that the fake edit will reveal your identity undesirably? Otherwise, why not just ask this question about _all_ downvotes?

Comment: Yeah, what @Stijn said. _Any_ content change should unlock votes. This is a bug or, at the very least, a missing "feature". (Nah, it's a bug.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah it will reveal my identity, i just want to get the matter done without revealing myself. But the system is not allowing me at this context.

Comment: @Stijn not a bug, its [by-design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150002/quick-edit-not-recorded-as-such-blocking-vote-change)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes a [missing feature](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256606/cannot-change-vote-even-though-the-post-has-been-edited)

Comment: @AzizShaikh If it is an intentionally missed feature then what would users with rep < 2k do..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: What about them? You should be more clear when you communicate (and this has nothing to do with which language you're speaking). What aspect of having <2k rep do you think is the problem?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry, i was talking about this. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

Comment: I'm <2k and my edits go to a review-cue, and I doubt a fake edit would pass that.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: Excellent. Always best to be clear. \@the rest of you, yes _I_ know that: I was trying to teach the OP to be clear.

Comment: Thos is one of the so-called features which are [[tag:status-broken-by-design]]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Does anybody have a genuine solutions to tackle this kind of situations?

Here are several strategies that can help:

- **Don't worry about it.** If you have a locked downvote and don't want to "reveal" yourself by making an edit, just leave it alone. Your single vote is unlikely to make much difference in the ultimate success of the question. If, as you say, the OP has edited the question to improve it, it's likely that other people will vote the question up despite your -1.
- **Wait for someone else to edit.** Sooner or later, just about everything on SO seems to be edited for some reason or other. You could speed along the process by asking the OP to clarify some aspect of the question, and there's no reason for the OP or anyone else to suspect that you voted a particular way simply because you left a comment.
- **Make a fake edit.** This feels like a crappy solution because it *is* a crappy solution. But if you feel that you need to do it, there's again no way for anyone to know that the person who made some silly little edit is the same person who downvoted. If you're really concerned about being identified, edit first and then wait 30 minutes before changing your vote.
- **Make a useful edit.** If you're going to bother editing something, you might as well do a good job. Most questions on SO are far from perfect, so spend a few minutes making a substantial improvement. This lets you reverse your vote without any presumption that the editor and down voter are the same person, and at the same time improves the question. That in turn could lead to additional up votes.

Comment: Tag editing is the best fake edit reasons. :)

Answer (score 10):

If you have edit privileges, which you do, then a fake edit to unlock votes seems like the way to go if you truly regret the downvote.

If you don't have edit privileges, then you can write a comment requesting the OP to edit the question "because I downvoted by mistake / I fatfingered the downvote button while trying to upvote / I deeply regret my downvote". If the OP cares, the OP will edit the post; win-win. If the OP doesn't care, then I guess that's a reason not to lose any sleep over this.

Comment: But this can't answer users like http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260293/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-locked-anonymous-down-vote#comment41480_260293

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy You can still ask the author of the answer to do the edit.

Comment: How about "I was in hurry to vote down, I couldn't wait for you to edit your post", which is usually the real reason to vote down answers ; ).

Comment: Basically we are hiding the identity of the down voters in order to avoid discrepancies between them. But this will explicitly reveal who did down vote to their post.

Answer (score 4):

There are many bug reports on this behavior:

- [Vote Can't Be Changed If Answer is Edited Too Quickly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78442/13295)
- [Quick Edit Not Recorded As Such Blocking Vote Change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150002/13295)
- [Unlock Votes If Post is Edited During the Grace Period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168553/13295)
- [Cannot Change Vote Even Though the Post has been Edited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256606/13295)

And the big one

- [Why Can't I Change My Vote if the Post has been Edited During the Initial 5mn Grace Period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23701/13295)

According to Jeff in the answer to that question, the 5 minute window for the downvote being locked should coincide with the 5 minute grace period for editing.  The problem is that you would have to change that vote within the five minute window.

The system still doesn't work, i.e. it doesn't consider the edit in the grace period an edit, after the five minute window has closed. The only alternative until they finally fix it is to **edit the question, then you can change your vote.**