# Make it easier to remove a bogus or accidental down-vote?

Tags: feature-request, downvotes

The inability to remove a down-vote from an answer after a short time has elapsed seems like an unnecessary restriction. One can work around it by editing the answer first, but it seems that this shouldn't be necessary, and what is the point of a restriction such as this if you can work around it anyway?

What prompted me to ask was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7187275/253056) where someone down-voted and left a comment, but then realised that they were mistaken in their objection to the answer, but were unable to remove their down-vote.

Comment: Edit the answer (make a minor improvement, there's always room for improvement) to unlock it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I understand how to work around this - but in this case the commenter who made the unfortunate down-vote would probably need to make the edit (since you only get a short window afterwards during which to remove the down-vote). Furthermore, the commenter probably isn't the best person to make any edits (in this case at least) and may not even have enough rep to do so. Either way, it seems like an unnecessary restriction - why shouldn't people be able to change their minds and remove a down-vote at any time, regardless of edits, etc ?

Comment: The reason that they can't undo their vote later is to discourage attempts to manipulate the answer ranking by downvoting all answers that are not your own. And in general, if someone felt compelled to downvote your answer, it is in need of an edit. Even if correct, it obviously wasn't clear enough. Or maybe it needs to explicitly address that point of confusion.

Comment: @CodyGray: I'm always happy to improve an answer if there is any sort of ambiguity or lack of clarity, but if you look at the answer I linked to you will see that the down-voter was simply confused about two very different technical terms - the answer was not unclear in this regard - the down-voter was probably just suffering from a temporary mental aberration due to lack of caffeine - it happens to us all from time to time. ;-)

Comment: May be [**this**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260293/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-locked-anonymous-down-vote) would be a helpful link for you.

Comment: @PaulR: There is not a "short window" after an edit to reverse a vote. The only window is the time after your vote is made. Once there's an edit, you have no time limit at all to change your vote. You could do it years later.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: thanks - looks like my question might be close enough to that one to be closed as a duplicate?...