# Can a moderator flag be considered from the time when it was asked?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags, revision-history

Almost a statement on something I read here not long ago on discussion of the Triage queue and the new "help and improvement" queue.

But I only recently just submitted a "flag" for "not an answer" on an answer that was given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28898545/2313887).

It does seem a bit silly an ask, but the general point was at the time the flag was submitted the "answer" was most certainly not an answer. But at subsequent times and leading up to the final edit that seems in place now it does actually resemble an answer, if not entirely correct through its revision stages, but eventually resulting in a statement which mimics the answer I provided myself after the flag was raised.

I would generally think a great big "so what", with the exception that it does get noted that a certain number of "declined flags" within a period causes my account ( or anyone's account as the point ) to not be able to "flag" posts anymore.

So it seems kind of arbitrary, but is there a practice to consider the revision history in moderator decisions such as deeming the "flag" with a "declined" status or similar?

It's not a major crippling thing. I'm just trying to help and if that counts as a negative to me when the content has been corrected since then it seems a reverse of the logic for which the initial action was intended. If I get shut off from being able to do the same from further legitimate problems then so be it. But the original intent was sound.

Discussion tag added for sake of adding a tag, though it will probably burn me again. But a valid thing to consider or invalid? Which is essentially the ask here.

Comment: "is there a practice to consider the revision history in moderator decisions" - well, _there isn't even any evidence in the revision history_ as the first 5 minutes of edits are just silently merged into the initial revision due to the grace period. For your specific example, the first revision visible in the history certainly doesn't merit a NAA flag. There have been many requests to make the initial version of the post a permanent part of the revision history, which have so far been declined.

Comment: @l4mpi Complete aggreement with the 5 minute principle which I did forget to mention.

Comment: Related: [Is it all right to flag very new answers as 'very low quality'?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253862).

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Agreed. That's useful content I did not find in a search. Thanks. But I'm asking and likely without much success, if there is any consideration to that. But I also suppose that was answered as well.

Comment: @NeilLunn There's a feature-request at MSE: [Recognize edits that happened after the VLQ flag but during grace period as flag-validating ones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231199) It's getting old, posted 10 months ago, but it's not status-declined.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Useful again. But also mostly my point here is because I raised the flag when I did it has actually been marked as "declined" and therefore kind of a "black mark" against myself ( at least with consideration to further flags. So the "spirit" was to ask could this information on revision be possibly be made available to those making that moderation decision. It doesn't seem so. But I still appreciate your efforts to inform.

Comment: Your flag went into the review queue and was handled from there. It was disputed by the community, not declined by a moderator.

Comment: You mentioned in the question and in a comment that you were concerned about black marks stemming from having flags declined. I'm pointing out that it wasn't. There's no black mark against you for having your flag *disputed*. If you understood the difference, you'd have used the correct terminology and this wouldn't be a question at all.

Comment: @BilltheLizard And yet you have a record of responding to me as if I do have a "black cloud". I suggest if you think there is an issue then you chat with me about what you think the issue is. The fact is I know than when `x ` amount of flags get declined in a period  ( doesn't seem to matter how many were accepted in contrast ) then you cannot submit any further flags until a period of time has passed. Much like an ill considered ban on activity, you're probably hurting more than benefiting by not considering the true context. Seems to be a big problem here.

Comment: Your "abuse of quotes" gives me "pain in my posterior" and should "cease immediately".  I suggest "Quoters Anonymous" or at least "search" for "Using quotation marks properly" on the "internets".

Answer (score 15):

This will nearly always be a non-issue.

As Bill pointed out, the specific example you reference was disputed anyway - which will never penalize you as the flagger.

But even if that wasn't the case, even if the flag had been declined, this wouldn't matter unless you were *fantastically unlucky* and started encountering and flagging these answers *all the time*.

No one does that. No one has that problem.

But... If you *did*... I would just tell you to take a deep breath next time you were about to flag, and ask yourself, "I've been striking out a lot lately - maybe I should slow down & see if a quick comment wouldn't resolve this situation?"

And *that* is the point of the declined-flag warning you refer to. Just a friendly reminder to stop and think a little bit.