# A moderator deleted someone's good post and it's my fault

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

The question [Firefox does not pick up css](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29705430/1529630) received [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29705647/1529630):

> You have some mistakes in your css code that you need to fix. This
>   site is good for validating code: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/
>   - just type your website address in the address bar.

That seemed just a comment which didn't answer the question. So I flagged it as "not an answer", downvoted, and voted to delete.

However, the answer was updated, adding this:

> When you type your address in, it gives you 4 errors. You will notice
>   that the first error references line 33, but is actually complaining
>   about the double quote that it found on line 32. That double quote
>   might be throwing off all the rest of your code.

Then it became a good answer. So I upvoted it. And I would have retracted the flag and the delete vote if I could, but it's not possible.

But now a moderator has deleted it because of my flag :(

Comment: Kudos to you for taking responsibility and following through.

Comment: Note that the question itself should be closed: typographical error and no relevant code shown. And a lack of basic debugging, if there are unresolved errors without mentioning them.

Comment: let's close this question, and with enough CV/DV's it should easy to delvote it away.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I undeleted it, since it seemed to provide enough value to justify that.

Yeah, sometimes posts can change between the time you flag them and when we act on them. Even after they're deleted, we'll see posts get edited into shape.

If you see this again, you can raise an "other" flag and explain what went on. If we think it should be undeleted, we can do so.

Comment: So does a mod see when a user flagged the post and does he looks at the post how it looked at the specific time? Especially what to do when I flagged an answer as NAA and the user changes the answer right before the grace period ends, so that there is now revision created?

Comment: @Rizier123 We see it as it is; but not the same as you see it. We see it without any links or formatting, we just see plain text. When I scanned it; it didn't appear to be an answer.  I've handed a few hundred flags today; so I'm not surprised that I missed one. Thanks for catching that and letting us know.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I think you handed a few flags too much today :) I'm not OP and I also didn't say anything about a specific flag, so *I'm not surprised that I missed one* this confuses me a bit. I was just curious if a mod looks at the answer as it was when it was flagged. But apparently ^ not. (Because I flagged an answer once which was just like: "I don't see why your code shouldn't work." and then he updated it during the grace period, so the flag got declined later. That's why I was curious)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker “We see it without any links or formatting, we just see plain text.” – That’s kind of sad. Have you considered opening a feature request on meta about it? ;)

Comment: @poke, I think that's by design though.

Comment: @poke They went out of their way to *remove* the links and formatting.  Posts that don't have any content outside of their links *should* be deleted.

Comment: @bradlarson do you sleep?

Comment: @Aggressor sleep, what is this? Can I eat it? (I think and hope that a mod always have enough sleep, so that he doesn't handle flags, when he's tired)

Answer (score 22):

It's not your *fault*, you did nothing wrong.

The answerer did do something mildly wrong -- posting a terribly incomplete answer to lock in the timestamp, then "ninja-edit"ing to add more content.  All edits within the first five minutes become part of the "original" revision publicly visible.

This is common enough to have its own name — [Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533) (FGITW). There are a whole host of potential problems with this, including having five minutes to steal someone else's answer and have the timestamps lie and say you had it first… but there are also benefits, when a well-known user does this it effectively marks the question as their territory, and other experts won't waste time writing their own answers (provided of course that they trust the first user to do it right), so it remains tolerated. But it does come with some risks — someone can see that placeholder version and cast perfectly legitimate votes and flags. But the answerer chose to game the system with a placeholder; they chose to accept the risks.

Comment: I'm not sure the "territory marking" is really a *positive*. It drives me *nuts* when users do this, no matter their rep level.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Sometimes it works out rather well, [case in point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657367/potential-net-x86-jit-issue#comment7869458_6657439)  When it's a deep problem, it's best if the tag experts decide on *one* person to chase it, instead of duplicating effort.

Comment: As you say, the answerer runs the risk. I think you have a good example, but the times I've seen FGITW get *bad* weren't on the hard problems :)

Comment: I would say the "territory marking" is absolutely wrong. Surely a much *better* idea is to leave a comment on the question, letting the user know that you're looking into it, eg: "I think it's related to this, I'll give a detailed answer below". I know I'm a relative n00b, but that's what I do. It gives immediate feedback to the question asker and lets them know they have your attention.

Comment: @Maverick: It's definitely better to use comments for that purpose, yes.  In the example I linked, I had been sharing my progress with the entire community as I went, making it easy for someone else to join in the analysis, since they could have done so without duplication of effort.

Comment: ["new feature to trigger saving current revision after comment may eventually make all this fastest-gun game much less appealing than it is now. No matter how fast answerer is..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253862/is-it-all-right-to-flag-very-new-answers-as-very-low-quality/289668#comment174083_289668)

Comment: _"...instead of duplicating effort"_ -- this seems like a non-problem to me. First, "duplicated" effort, especially on complex problems, is often desirable, as different people approach complex problems differently, and offer different viewpoints and even solutions. As far as _"sharing my progress with the entire community"_ goes, it seems to me that if this is the goal, the answer can be worked collaboratively via the site's chat feature, rather than putting an incomplete answer out there.

Comment: Even ignoring the other problems, pity the poor questioner who keeps seeing notifications his question's been answered when it hasn't actually been.