# Moderator view for user flags needs an update!

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, moderators

So first to clear some things out. I read this [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291022/a-moderator-deleted-someones-good-post-and-its-my-fault/291024#comment180399_291024) on this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291024/3933332):

> So **does a mod see when a user flagged the post** and does he looks at the post how it looked at the specific time? Especially what to do when I flagged an answer as NAA and the user changes the answer right before the grace period ends, so that there is now revision created? –  **Rizier123** Apr 21 at 20:21
>
> @Rizier123 **We see it as it is;** but not the same as you see it. We see it without any links or formatting, **we just see plain text**. When I scanned it; it didn't appear to be an answer. I've handed a few hundred flags today; so I'm not surprised that I missed one. Thanks for catching that and letting us know. –  **George Stocker♦** Apr 21 at 20:26

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this sounds for me as a mod would only see the post as plain text in the latest version as it is.

And if this is correct, I think the view how a moderator sees a flag should be updated and he should see **more** than only the plain text of the latest version!

Just to give an example here:

I flagged this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29950396/3933332) when it was at [revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29950396/1) as NAA:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

And as you can see it got declined. And I think this is due to the fact that a mod only sees the latest version of the answer and he doesn't see when I flagged the answer and how the answer looked like at this specific time.

So if I'm correct with my understanding of the comment above, I kinda can understand why it got declined when a mod only sees the latest version of a post.

But for me this screams for an update of the view which moderators has when they handle flags.

So I would request that the view how a moderator sees flags gets a new layout/interface. I think a moderator should see the revisions of the post with the specific time when it got changed and he should also see which action happened at which state of the post (Maybe he should even see the comments on the post, since they are maybe important to the flag).

So with my *amazing* paint skills this could look something like this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Because I think right now this is not ideally how  mods see flags. So is something like this realistic which could be implemented? Or did I not understand the comment above properly?

Comment: link only answers are still answers, so it likely still would have been declined even with no revisions.

Comment: @KevinB At revision 1 the guy only asked OP questions and didn't answer the question (*link only answers are still answers* I don't think so, if the link breaks the answer would be with no value). But now this is not the point of my question here. I'm asking for a new layout how moderators see user flags

Comment: I feel your pain. Here's a comment I left in regards to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29970503/) being low/poor quality I might add, where it doesn't explain anything. Learn they say; how? *Try this my ******. 
*I wonder what goes on in people's heads. Stack wants us to flag low quality posts and mine was disputed. What does this say about their flag options? Sweet "you know what"...* - Moderators need to sharpen their kitchen knives, far as I'm concerned.

Comment: My point was it's just a bad example. The original answer was just a link only answer, so a NAA flag would have been declined no matter how much information was given in the moderator's list of flags to.. moderate. It's a low quality answer. At revision 1, the link did exist.

Comment: @KevinB: Link-only answer belong killed immediately with prejudice, read the famous castle post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer And first revision was some comments asking for clarification and a link with the helpful announcement "this link might help".

Comment: Is that not what the VLQ flag/queue is for?

Comment: @KevinB: No, that's not what the VLQ flag is for. But the queue handles both NAA and VLQ flags.

Comment: I think it's just a matter of opinion at this point. I see the answer as an "attempt" to answer the question, with a request for clarification as a part of that attempt. you seem to not even see it as an attempt.

Comment: I'll agree at *"an attempt to answer"*, but if a butcher can't back his craft/trade with a good and edible piece of meat, then he's obviously not in the right field and using poorly sharpened tools to work with. @KevinB ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure I would want a moderator acting on a now-useful post just because it used to be a sub-par post. Which is essentially what would end up happening here. Otherwise, what would be the point of this? To have the mods say, "Oh, yeah, they're right, this answer was terrible. Now it's not." and give you a helpful flag even though there is no reason for them to act on the flag at this point? How would this help anything, except to boost "helpful" flag counts when an OP takes the time to fix their post? How do you expect this to change mod behavior?

Comment: @Fred-ii- - FYI, moderators had nothing to do with the handling of your flag: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7897176

Comment: @Rizier123 It's not clear to me what moderation benefit would be gained by implementing a view like this. If a flagged post was once bad, but it's good by the time a moderator gets around to it, the moderator should treat it like a good post. Your flag was *de facto* not helpful (i.e., it turned out not to improve the the site), even if flagging was the right thing to do at the time. Maybe there just needs to be better education that a declined flag is not an insult and just means that your flag ended up not being helpful, either due to a mistake on your part *or* the passage of time.

Comment: @Kendra declined flags counts against you. So if you flag an answer as e.g. NAA, but then the user updates it and it's not a NAA anymore the flag counts against you and maybe even end up, that you can't flag anymore  because you have too many declined flags

Comment: @apsillers The point is: **declined flags counts against you** See my comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291974/moderator-view-for-user-flags-needs-an-update?noredirect=1#comment184846_291974

Comment: @BradLarson My mistake Brad. Well, it just goes to show then, that the people who approved it, support low-quality questions and probably give low-quality answers also. My apologies to the moderators.

Comment: @Rizier123 And how will this change that? If when the mod gets to it, there is nothing for them to do and no need for them to handle the post, it is no longer a helpful flag. That's just a fact of life. My point was more, _what do you expect mods to do with this new information?_  I would expect mods to see the revision, if this were implemented, nod a little that it _was originally_ a bad post, and then decline the flag anyway purely because the flag was no longer helpful and there was no need for them to get involved.

Comment: @Rizier123 I'm aware that declined flags negatively impact your flags' weight and can earn you a temporary flag ban. However, I think this problem is rare enough that it's not likely to seriously impact your flag weight. (I am ready to entertain the argument that my estimate here is wrong.) I think the negative impact of moderators wasting time deciding whether a post *used to* be bad (which gets us no benefit in site quality, because the post is already good) outweigh the minor negative impact to a user's flags' weight.

Comment: @apsillers If you think about it a user *could* post just spam an such stuff, then change it to a good answer and your flag gets declined. If he makes it enough times, you can't flag anymore, because the declined flags counts against you and you get a temp flag ban! *I think this problem is rare enough* Well I have to say that happened to me already 3-4 times and this number will increase, when I flag NAA posts and they change it then!

Comment: @Rizier123 If a flag is raised for spam, the answer changes, and the mod looks at it, I would expect the moderator to raise an eyebrow at that and take a look at the revision history. I've seen mods say several times that if they feel there is something that needs looked into behind a flag, they will visit the post and check the revision history to try to figure out why the post was flagged. NAA flags, however, are nowhere near as severe as a spam or offensive flag, so I would not expect a mod to bother checking into a NAA flag.

Comment: @Kendra There we go ^! We already have it, they need to go to the post itself, because they don't see it when they handle the flag, so why not just include it in the view when they handle flags?! Then they might also see some stuff which they wouldn't have seen

Comment: Look at the very low quality queue. How much more complex would that view be if you also were presented the last, say, 1 or two revisions, if not all of them?

Comment: Well, I can now confirm that the (my) flag that was rejected, came from people who either give low quality answers themselves, or know squat about the question/functions/related code in question. They just click on "Looks good" without reading the question and what's involved while probably gaining some points for badges; *truly pathetic*.

Comment: Because there's no _need_ for it. They don't need to see the revisions on every single flag raised. They should be evaluating flags based on how the content currently looks, which they're doing a fine job of. The exceptions are the more severe flags that appear to be raised on a good post. Why should the devs clutter up the flag interface when nine times out of ten the mods probably won't even need the added feature? Why slow the mods down more by adding something else they need to check for each flag? What is the greater benefit here, minus a few more helpful flags?

Comment: @Rizier123 If a user posts honest-to-goodness *spam* or *offensive content*, and then covers it up with a legitimate question, then (1) that's a pretty high level of dedication for a spammer or troll, and (2) you should raise a custom moderator flag to point out this sophisticated toxic behavior. If by "spam" you just mean a lousy post that later gets polished into a better post: if this happens at least 25% of the time you raise a flag (the threshold for a temporary ban), then I'd say you have exceptionally bad luck.

Comment: @apsillers To point 1: Since we are on the internet, I kinda expecting everything, I mean *everything*!,  So I wouldn't be surprised if someone would do that (But that's not the point). I mean I got 1 declined flag since a long time from the answer above in my question and I already get a notification: *Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined - please review them before flagging this post!* <- Just from 1 declined flag! (My next declined flag is a while back!)

Comment: @Rizier123 According to the [documented behavior](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405) that's probably because you've raised 9 helpful flags and one declined flag within the last week. If you raise 2 more declined flags and *0 helpful flags* then you will be temporarily blocked until your oldest declined flag expires (7 days after you raised it). If you raise any helpful flags, your weekly declined-ratio will drop below 10% and the warning will disappear. If you'd like to make a feature request to consider long-term good standing in calculating flag bans, that seems like a reasonable idea.

Comment: @apsillers http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287211/3933332 Apparently since a month or so there is "aged away". I think if moderators would use this for such flags where an edit or so made the flag "invalid" I would totally be okay with this and I would think this would be the right thing to do here. Because this wouldn't count neither for or against the user. (But declined is just wrong here I think)

Comment: Agree we need to fix the moderator view for flags, in many, many ways. But the flag you build your case around is a terrible example - expecting moderators *or anyone else* to approve the flag if it's still active on a post that has been corrected as dramatically as that one is crazy: the problem simply no longer exists. Ironically, if you'd flagged it as Very Low Quality, the edit itself would've marked the flag "helpful"; NAA doesn't work that way though.

Comment: @Shog9 *Ironically, if you'd flagged it as Very Low Quality, the edit itself would've marked the flag "helpful"; NAA doesn't work that way though.* lol :) Well that's good to know so I will more flag an answer as LQ so if they improve it 1. A mod doesn't need to look at it, since it's automatically marked as helpful 2. And I don't run into the problem that a mod sees the post at a different state as I flagged it.

Comment: @Shog9 *if you'd flagged it as Very Low Quality, the edit itself would've marked the flag "helpful"* <- Would that mean if someone would flag an answer with like 100 upV as LQ and the user updates it it gets marked as helpful ? Or how do I have to understand that?

Comment: You can't flag upvoted posts as VLQ, @Rizier123. Generally you should reserve that flag for stuff that appears completely irredeemable without author intervention.

Comment: @Shog9 *You can't flag upvoted posts as VLQ* I never tried it so I didn't knew that one :) *Agree we need to fix the moderator view for flags, in many, many ways* Maybe you want to post an answer what you think about my idea for the "new" layout or say what you would want/what you think

Comment: It would be good if there was either (a) a way to request a deeper investigation into rejected flags to reassess them based on the revision history (e.g. offensive comments edited out) (b) have history shown on reviews and a "out of date" (i.e. not rejected) reason where action has been taken to fix the post.

Answer (score 16):

I'm totally on board with fixing the formatting of links in the moderator flag summary page. If there are links in a post, the summarized version we see in the list of flags should have those links highlighted. We shouldn't have to go to the full post to see that there are links in this text. I know there have been instances of spam that weren't immediately obvious from the flag queue due to the links being hidden.

While we're at it, it would be nice if they brought back the old coloring scheme where the titles of answers are grey and the titles of questions blue. Under the new design, all titles are the same blue color in the moderator flag queue, which makes it impossible to pick out which flagged posts are answers and which questions. That has led to some accidental deletions when questions were read as being answers.

I'm not as big a fan of the history view you're talking about. That would clutter up the flag queue with a lot of information that is irrelevant for almost all posts.  Also, how would that help us to act on a flagged post? If whatever the post was flagged for (lacking some details, having a swear word within it, etc.) has been corrected by the community, did we even need to be involved to begin with?

Out of courtesy, I sometimes will dig into the history of a flagged post (we already have access to a timeline view like the above) and mark a flag as helpful if it was about something that has been fixed, but this isn't a common occurrence. Again, if the community has corrected the problem without our involvement, did the flag need to be cast?

Comment: Perhaps if intervening edits occur, the flag should never be *declined*.  Whether it is best to use *disputed* or a new resolution *overcome by edit* or such, I cannot say.  (If implemented, this feature should be aware of ninja edits.  Even though the minor revisions aren't saved, the system should know the last edit came after the flag)

Comment: Agreed that valid flags that are then fixed by an edit should be disputed at worst. Yes, the community fixed it, but how could the flagger expect that?

Comment: @BenVoigt I would agree with this. But the *declined* is just counting against you and stands for like: "The flag was wrong, because there was nothing to handle", but you flagged it at another time where there was something to handle. So if you get a declined flag it's like: "Don't flag such stuff there was nothing to handle". And I think this is wrong. I think you should tell a user if his flag was good/correct or bad. And I think since a few weeks there is also the thing:"aged away", which would probably be something which could be used for something like this

Comment: *"If whatever the post was flagged for (lacking some details, having a swear word within it, etc.) has been corrected by the community, did we even need to be involved to begin with?"* - This part "lacking some details". I won't retype all over again, it's in [this comment that I left...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291974/moderator-view-for-user-flags-needs-an-update#comment184857_291974).

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287211/3933332 Seems like since a month or so there is  "aged away", so wouldn't that be the right thing to do for a moderator to say: it aged away. So it neither counts for or against the user?!

Comment: @Fred-ii- - I'm not sure what that has to do with this. The post wasn't edited, and your flag was disputed in review. It is still an attempt at answering a question, so a flag requesting immediate deletion for something like that will most likely be declined or disputed in review. If you feel that is a bad answer, downvote it and move on.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Just so you know, according to the flag definitions, that post you linked to is [not VLQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161095/do-one-line-of-code-answers-count-as-vlq) (someone could salvage it by editing in an explanation) and it is [not NAA](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag) (it is not another question or request for clarification).

Comment: .....approved by people who know absolutely squat (I spared the other s-word) about MySQL/PDO. Rejected by guys who know what they're talking about like showdev and Ed Cottrell. *Giving my head another serious shake*. Ok, I got the message but being barred for too many rejected flags, gets my goat.

Comment: @apsillers Not VLQ? Exactly, it's worse than very low quality. It says absolutely nothing but "Try this" with nothing to back it up. Sorry, but if someone hasn't already edited their answer given comments to ask them why they should "Try this", then it should be flagged/deleted. Here I thought Stack wanted to have a strong and quality base of Q&A's. That says a lot about the integrity of members who will only keep posting low quality and uninformative answers.

Comment: @Fred-ii- If you believe the scope of VLQ should expand to include code-only answers, I would craft a new definition that incorporates that category of answer (while being careful to word it in a way that doesn't wrongly include other categories of posts) and include it in carefully-considered `[feature-request]` weighing the pros and cons of deleting such answers versus merely letting the community downvote them. (I am 100% serious. If you can argue the site would be better with such posts deleted, then make your case in a new `[feature-request]`. It seems like a reasonable proposition.)

Comment: You're right @apsillers and it is a reasonable proposition. If I may just elaborate a bit more on the "Try this" concept; a "try this", in my view (*and many others will agree*), should be used in conjunction with an informative answer. For example; an opening about where faults were made, followed by fixed code, and/or where errors are, "then" followed by a "If that doesn't fix it, then **try** the following... etc. That type of answer I have seen many times and often receive many positive votes. If we don't let the newbies know, then they'll just keep on giving low quality answers.

Comment: @BradLarson Would that be a possible that moderators click on "aged away", since they don't count for nor against the user for such flags as described in my question ?

Comment: @Rizier123 [See this for how flags get marked "aged away".](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204327/when-are-moderator-flags-automatically-dismissed-as-aged-away-by-the-system) It's strictly a time-based setting, not a manually selected one.

Comment: @Kendra Then can't we change it that mods also can trigger it manually? I think this would match perfectly for flags which were valid at the time they were flagged, but now don't need any attention anymore. Because they "aged away" from an action like an edit which the user made. Also it wouldn't count against nor for the user.

Comment: @Rizier123 I could see having a different status for mods to assign, but I don't think "aged away" would work for this purpose. If someone manually sets it, it would feel like a mislabel to call it that because the _flag_ didn't age away, the need for action did.

Comment: @Kendra But I think it's more or less clear, that a *declined* is the wrong thing to trigger for a flag which were valid at the time it was flagged. I think now it's just a question what else a mod could do, so that it would neither count against nor for the user.

Comment: To me it seems like requiring the mod to both check the validity of the flag now and at the time it was raised would be unneeded additional work. the only benefit of the additional work would be to reduce the chance that the person flagging gets a temporarily flag ban, which I don't think is that big of a problem.. If you're in danger of being flag banned, maybe you should bit more cautious on what flags are cast, for example, waiting to see if the owner of the post is going to actively improve it.

Answer (score 3):

The [new moderator flag dashboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330171/295232) shows an [edited] label if the post has been edited after the flag has been cast:

[image]

This isn't exactly what the author of this question proposed, but it does provide a visual indicator that *something* has changed and makes it more likely that the ♦ moderator will investigate not only the latest version of the post but its entire history.