# Flag declined because of subsequent edit

Tags: discussion, edits, flags, declined-flags

At this time I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26344717/laravel-eloquent-or-where-is-not-null/33265953#33265953) it was a link-only answer (I used VLQ). Later someone edited it to add some content from the link, and a moderator declined my flag (correctly, since at that point it was no longer link-only). Shouldn't the edit have invalidated my flag?

Comment: There is no "link only" flag so what flag did you use?  Custom?  Or NAA?  Or VLQ? (it may be relevant to the answer)

Comment: @psubsee2003 Excuse me, what's " NAA"?

Comment: @Kotshi **N**ot **A**n **A**nswer

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291974/3933332

Answer (score 3):

No, the edit shouldn't have invalidated the flag, because not every edit to every flag worthy question will remove the problem(s) causing the post to be flagged.  It would mean that people making minor edits not actually fixing the core problem(s) would remove the flags indicating those core problems.