# Declined flag - not an answer after edit

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I recently reported [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38795896/1) when it popped up on the site. After flagging as "Not an Answer", I moved on and continued answering questions on the site.

Today, I log into my account, and I see this:
[image]

This was clearly not an answer at the time I reviewed this post. Is this intended behavior? Should an edit to this post not invalidate my flags, or at least to the moderator show the post (at the time I reported it)?

Comment: Welcome to the club: http://imgur.com/a/AGCX8 I got one too :P (Also related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291974/3933332)