# Why were the flags I raised to these two answers declined?

Tags: discussion, edits, declined-flags, link-only-answers

I flagged the following two answers as link-only answers (before they were edited):

1. [1st answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58394795) ([revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58394795/revisions))
2. [2nd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58484615) ([revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58484615/revisions))

However, both of my flags were declined. Why?

Why is it a duplicate? I think moderators handle flag when rage. I flag an answer when it's link only. Where am I wrong?

Comment: I assume the flags were made before the additional details were added to the answers?

Comment: yep  .  :(  .      sorry

Comment: The first one was not a link-only answer to begin with. *"The given data was invalid." is hard coded* is an (attempt to) answer.

Comment: Data is invalid. What data is invalid with link.?

Comment: I am sorry I'm not aware of the exact process.  What happends to a flag when a post get edited? Is the review presented with the post before or after the edit? What is or should be the result for the flag?

Comment: I won't speak for moderators; but this outcome -- that the answers were edited with more detail, is exactly the outcome I'm hoping for. Whether it was because you flagged it or because someone else found it organically and helped to fix it, this is the best case for how this goes.  The OP doesn't get ticked that their post is deleted, people who visit the answer get the information they need, and we all prosper.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moderator view for user flags needs an update!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291974/moderator-view-for-user-flags-needs-an-update)

Comment: They [did update the moderator view for user flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332286/moderator-flag-dashboard-hard-launch), @gnat. I'm pretty sure the new view clearly indicates if the post was edited since the flag was raised. What they didn't do was push a firmware update to the moderators themselves, so we aren't really conditioned to paying attention to that or caring about the consequences.

Answer (score 12):

So…a couple of things.

First off, I want to echo [George Stocker's words in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390884/why-were-the-flags-i-raised-to-these-two-answers-declined#comment738051_390884). He declines to speak for moderators, but I'm going to let him do so anyway:

> […] this outcome -- that the answers were edited with more detail, is exactly the outcome I'm hoping for. Whether it was because you flagged it or because someone else found it organically and helped to fix it, this is the best case for how this goes.  The OP doesn't get ticked that their post is deleted, people who visit the answer get the information they need, and we all prosper.

Someone should nominate that guy for moder…oh wait. Anyway, sage advice. He nails the entire point of flags—bringing things you perceive as problematic to moderator attention. If the end result is that the site's content is improved, well then that's a win for everyone.

Second, your "not an answer" flag on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58394795) was declined by a moderator who isn't named Cody Gray on October 15th at 15:19 UTC. The edit was submitted by YesThatIsMyName on October 16th at 7:25 UTC. As such, your assumption that the moderator declined your "not an answer" flag because of the edit that had already been submitted is incorrect. The edit hadn't been submitted at the time your flag was declined. The moderator was declining your "not an answer" flag based on the original text of the post—namely, this:

> "The given data was invalid." is hard coded
>
> https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/22112/commits/b70372fd0031e5fabaee462c913b19b665becaf3

Per [the guidance on when "not an answer" flags are appropriate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer), your flag was invalid. That *was* an answer. The answer was that very first sentence. Importantly, it was *not* a "link-only" answer. The link was merely supplemental, serving as additional evidence of the assertion made in the first paragraph. Paying a bit more attention, and reading the answer in the context of the question, it becomes clear that the answer is saying:

> You cannot translate the string, "The given data is invalid.", because that particular string is hard-coded in the Laravel 5.6 framework code.
>
> <Link to commit where hard-coded string can be seen.>

Obviously, I'm not going to argue that the answer is of exceptional quality. I think it's quite clear that it could be easily edited to substantially improve its clarity. But it *is*, in fact, an answer to the question, so your flag was invalid, and this had nothing to do with any subsequent edit. I would have declined that flag as well.

Third, on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57519946/how-to-show-a-custom-error-message-on-entering-an-email-input-field-with-other-t/58484615#58484615), the timeline matches your theory. I suspect you are correct that the moderator declined your flag without noticing that the post had been edited to incorporate the relevant example code. That is, I suppose, somewhat annoying to you as a flagger, but ultimately of little consequence, considering that the problem has been resolved in a mutually beneficial way. As such, I don't really want to dwell on it, other than to say that I agree that a "not an answer" flag on a post that looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58484615/1) is a correct flag.

Finally, your question here comes off as a bit confrontational. I'm not sure if it's just a language gap that's causing me to misread it, but the phrase, *"I thinks mod handle flag when rage."* sticks in my craw a bit. What exactly do you mean by that? Do you mean that moderators handle flags when they're angry, and that we decline flags out of spite? I can assure you that this is definitely not the case. Have I been made angry a few times while handling flags? Undoubtedly, yes. But I *still* don't take it out of the flaggers.