# Duplicating existing answers, aka. "loot stealing"

Tags: discussion, answers, fastest-gun

This is unfortunately a common scenario I noticed. There is some question with no correct answers. One user provides a slightly different answer (which happen to be correct), and suddenly within a couple of minutes there are plenty of similar answers (usually from low-reputation users), or even worse some of the existing answers are edited to include the correct solution.

As a result, the answerer is losing their loot. I mean, I have enough reputation already so it doesn't hurt me so much; however, it can be quite painful when someone has just started building their reputation. Sure, one could say "that's life, try again" and would be right, but shouldn't we punish the thief?

One of the examples: [ActiveRecord doesn't save user name and email value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442439/activerecord-doesnt-save-user-name-and-email-value/32442747?noredirect=1#comment52750748_32442747)

Second answer is a theft attempt. The user posted an incorrect answer, after about 10 minutes, another user posted a correct answer, and 2 minutes later the first user pretty much copied it. I am absolutely fine with the third answer, as it puts much more explanation to the problem.

Another one (this time, I'm "robbed" - 6 minutes difference): [passing a hash to a route in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443018/passing-a-hash-to-a-route-in-rails?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Comment: Convincing SE to "punish" users for editing their post or that the best answer cannot be arrived at by collaboration is going to be a very hard sell.  There are no old men in the fastest gun of the West game, time to hangup your spurs.  That good answer is still good when it posted ten minutes after to slingers stopped paying attentions.

Comment: @HansPassant - The main problem I have with those situation is that those users do not even try to contribute to the community, but are only after points. Those answers are completely pointless, they do not add anything new to the discussion. I've seen couple of cases when such an answer has been added to a very old questions (with an identical answer upvoted hundreds of time). For me this is pretty much the same as `100k gold please`

Comment: Yes, SE designed it that way, gamification was quite intentional.  Playing the game all the way to 100k is very rare, most users peter out between 10 and 20k.  Like you did.  And yes, there are a *lot* of new players since April this year.

Comment: system has a feature that could help in cases like that. If you [comment incorrect answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289668/839601) _immediately_ after posting your, all changes to these made after your comments will be considered separate revisions with timestamps later than your answer

Comment: @gnat But who's going to do that? Answering alone is time-consuming enough. Finding something useful to comment to other questions that really don't need any comment won't make it better. But maybe it could be applied to users known to display this conduct. I wouldn't notice them though.

Comment: @GertArnold when there is contention between multiple answers within [meta-tag:grace-period] timeframe, it hardly looks time consuming to me. Let's not pretend that we're talking about [processing of sorted arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/839601) or [OO-principles that are practically applicable for Javascript](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/180588/31260)

Comment: I don't think the system can/should handle the loot answers, I believe voting is enough to discourage loots

Comment: I know this is an old question, but in the second example it looks to me (not a SME), as if the newer answer suggests something different than your answer. There is a parameter given to the `model_path` function, while your answer focuses on spacing/parsing alone.

Comment: Wow, resurrecting an 8 years old question - the new Indiana Jones movie clearly wakes an archeologist in all of us? :) The issue in the question was unrelated to params, it was the space that was the issue, not the lack of parameter, especially that the questions states they tried adding model.id. In this case extra space changes the behaviour. In any case, I don't really care :P

Comment: Can we stop bumping this old post, editors? 4 minor edits to nitpick grammar is a bit... much

Answer (score 8):

There's two major possibilities. First, that someone is lurking on these questions, waiting for someone to answer and then quickly using that information to create a second answer.

The second possibility is that multiple people are independently working on a problem and find a solution in roughly the same amount of time, within a few minutes of each other.

I know that I've been in the second category, I did a bunch of research and testing and once I had the answer, someone else had already posted something that was substantially similar, or better, a minute or two faster than me.

I think that if you're going to make this kind of accusation, you'd want to show that one user has a history of behavior that looks like "loot stealing."

Comment: I agree that there are two options. Somehow however when the second option happens then usually the later answer is deleted (been there many times; seen user deleting answers even with some upvotes just because it was not adding anything)

Comment: I was just thinking, since you have over 10K rep, you can see the deleted posts etc. All that stuff is invisble to me.

Comment: That would cover first example, in a second example the accepted answer owner did edit my answer just couple of minutes before he posted his. Still not sure why it displays as first when they are sorted by `oldest`

Comment: I am very new to the community and I have also been in the second category. My thought process after taking quite some time and effort( to double check and validate my answer) and posting an answer only to find out someone else has posted a similar one is that leavubg my post up will do no harm. I feel this because most users would prefer an answer from a person with more reputations and deleting my post will just mean all my time and efforts are wasted. That being said, I do understand your view of "loot stealing" and genuinely want to know what should I do if I find myself on the other end.