# Auto-converting answers to comments is a PITA

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

1. I know the answer to a question!
2. I post the answer, intending to flesh it out in the next couple minutes. This is great because it ensures the user gets an answer ASAP, often within a matter of *seconds*, and in another minute I can flesh out the answer.
3. No, sorry, the answer is auto-converted to a comment.
4. I can't add another answer for 60 seconds.

This is a comically bad user experience. Can we treat answerers like adults please?

Recent experience: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35930336/1339987

Quoting a 320 vote [meta answer on The Fastest Gun In The West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9758/183887):

> ### I do NOT want to, in any way, discourage the quick and dirty answer.

Well, we're doing that now, so let's not.

### Update:

Probably a corner case where the link to an SO question in the answer triggered the conversion. I find this business logic more understandable.

Comment: *"This is great because it ensures the user gets an answer ASAP, often within a matter of seconds"* Why is this great? It's not like the question is going anywhere.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara it's pretty self-evident why faster is better. discussed to death here http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9758/183887

Comment: Sample answer you've linked to in the post is unrelated to the question at all - definitely should be comment. If you feel that question is already answered - vote as duplicate.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov it's tricky but I did the right thing. It's likely an XY problem for the user and that would make this a first-class answer. It certainly is an XY problem for future visitors who would happily stop trying to implement `sort` and instead use built-in. But the OP might be just trying to learn to do X so I can't exactly close as duplicate.

Comment: Auto-conversion to a comment? I didn't even know this was a thing. How long has this been in effect?

Comment: @MikeM. Many years.

Comment: Even if you weren't triggering an auto-conversion-to-comment, a short incomplete (crappy) answer is likely to trigger an auto-downvote-by-an-experienced-user, so this is a risk you take when abusing the answer box. I'm not really clear on why you want to streamline the process of posting poor-quality answers?

Comment: @CodyGray even-more-experienced-user would do not only that but also quickly flag VLQ and immediately post a brief comment like ["this answer looks incomplete, why?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289668/839601) (a while ago system has been tweaked to make it safe and fun game for such a user)

Comment: @CodyGray you're mostly right but I find it frustrating that there's *extremely* broken workflows that happen in edge cases, and that *some* of those edge cases are legitimate exceptions, in this case, where a short answer is savvy. Broken to the extent like, "What you just wrote will disappear, it will be moved to a comment, if you try removing the comment to write an answer satisfactory to the bot and possibly half-asleep review queuers, you will be punished with a 60 second delay." Pure punishment for trying to do the right thing. Edge cases should not be machete cases.

Comment: My instinct is succinct but rantish complaints on meta in an interest to raise the user concern. Not exactly what meta receives well (twice it's just devolved into what exactly I might have done better in my example post, which doesn't prove better examples don't exist, guess I'll learn). I'm thinking about a better proposal or at least a more nuanced description of the problem. This has happened to me a few times, where weaponized edge cases in features meant to dissuade shoddy participation leave the user with a feeling of punishment.

Comment: I don't know, I can't be very sympathetic. You say "edge case", but this has ***never*** happened to me. Maybe I am just too long-winded.

Comment: Having to wait 60 seconds before trying to answer again is really, really, really bad. ;)

Comment: @Trilarion it creates a strong feeling of punishment. Furthermore, yes, it is, this is 2016, it's not acceptable for a website to "freeze" for a minute.

Comment: The website isn't freezing, you're being slowed down for providing sub-par content. This is a good thing.

Comment: @djechlin The fact that you're feeling like you're being punished for providing low quality content in an attempt to cheat the system sounds very much like a [meta-tag:status-bydesign].

Answer (score 32):

> I know the answer to a question!

Great, then post *an answer to the question* rather than a placeholder so that you can edit in an *actual* answer later, while trying to make it appear in the history as if you provided an actual answer quicker than you did.

> I post the answer, intending to flesh it out in the next couple minutes. This is great because it ensures the user gets an answer ASAP, often within a matter of seconds, and in another minute I can flesh out the answer.

If you're posting *complete* answers up to an acceptable quality standard for the site, then this wouldn't be happening.  If this is happening to you, then what you are posting is woefully incomplete.  Take the extra couple of minutes to post an acceptable answer *before* submitting it.

> This is a comically bad user experience. Can we treat answerers like adults please?

Can you treat others as adults, rather than going out of your way to post low quality content in a (apparently often unsuccessful) attempt to earn more rep by posting lower quality content?  Have some pride in the quality of the content you post to the site; all of it, not just some of it.

As for your example, you shouldn't be posting answers to questions that just link to another SO question.  If you feel that such a link sufficiently answers the question, then you, by definition, feel that the question should be closed as a duplicate.  Vote to close, don't post an answer.

Comment: I posted to use Collections.sort and linked to an answer explaining how. This is what auto-converted.

Comment: It was a complete answer. When I reposted it (and added like an extra sentence to play nice with the bot?) the user commented thanks and added an upvote. User did not seem to feel belittled or treated like a child. Answer seemed to be useful to user.

Comment: As to your last point, this one's tricky but I did the right thing. It's a likely XY problem for the OP and certainly is an XY problem for future visitors to the question. But I don't have enough evidence that it's an XY problem because the user might be interested in learning to do the "X" for themselves. So I couldn't close it but I had to acknowledge that it was a first-class answer for many future visitors and 50% probably the OP.

Comment: Is that what triggered the bot? If so I can make a more specific post on this corner case.

Comment: @djechlin If you don't understand the question to know well enough what the answer is, then you should post a comment to ask a clarifying question.  That's literally exactly what comments are for.  If it's clear that the post is a duplicate, then vote to close it as a duplicate.  Answers are not the place to try to gather information about what the question is.

Comment: No, doesn't matter, I'm answering for future visitors too. Good questions pretty often have multiple (2 or 3, not like dozens) of correct answers.

Comment: @djechlin And given that you have no idea what the question is actually asking (by your own admission) it's *not a good question*.  It's apparently quite unclear to you what it is actually asking.  If you care about the future visitors, then work to improve the question so that it's clear what it's asking, so others will know, when looking at it, if it matches their situation.  This is exactly why question quality is important, and we don't want to just flood the site with tons of low quality questions with low quality answers.

Comment: I upvoted it after some thought. It's a pretty good question. You can't really expect users to talk about possible XY problems they might be solving the X on unwittingly.

Comment: Also I'd like to point out that we really clearly value being able to figure out the user's problem before they do. Here's one example I recall http://stackoverflow.com/a/1563668/1339987 so it's really weird that you're lecturing me on how I shouldn't do try to do this, it contradicts what I see literally every day on this site.

Comment: @djechlin So it's a good question, and you think its clear what it's asking, even though you have no idea what it's asking and have no idea whether or not the answer you posted actually answers the question.  That is a contradiction.  If the question is a good question, it should be clear.  That is a *necessity* of a good question. For you to think that it's a good question would be to say that you find it very clear what it's asking, meaning you would know that the link you provide either conclusively is, or is not, a duplicate.

Comment: @djechlin That answer is a mess.  At a minimum it needs a ton of editing work.  And of course it's seven years old.  Do you really want to stick with that as a shining example of a great process?

Comment: I think it's absurd you're trying to lecture me on how we don't try to figure out users problems before they narrow them down themselves. Have you visited SO in the last 5 years? Like I said #offtherails, bye.

Comment: @djechlin I didn't say that we don't try to figure out what a user's problem is, or to help them improve their unclear question into one that's answerable.  I'm saying that's what comments are for.  You're posting a comment as an answer, and then complaining when it's being converted to a comment *entirely correctly*.  Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318735/auto-converting-answers-to-comments-is-a-pita/318736?noredirect=1#comment320275_318736 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318735/auto-converting-answers-to-comments-is-a-pita/318736?noredirect=1#comment320281_318736

Comment: The issue is not I "have no idea what it's asking about." It's a potential XY problem. The user perfectly clearly explained X. Another user posted an answer to X. I posted an answer to Y. I was satisfied that the user was now guaranteed to have a correct answer (thanks to the clarity of their question) and felt it was *essential* to post an answer to Y for *future visitors.* Asking for clarification was a waste of time because I would have just as well had to post "I know you're not looking for this, but future visitors might, so be aware you can do this" as an answer.

Comment: @djechlin So you posted an answer knowing full well that it very clearly didn't answer the question?  You know that that's not what answers are for.  If you want to provide information that you think might be helpful, but that is not an attempt to answer the question, then that's what comments are for, not answers.

Comment: I pretty frequently post answers that will be useful for future visitors who have the question in the title (or the Y to the question's title) moreso than the question on the user's brain... that's correct, that's good practice and we encourage it.

Comment: @djechlin No, it's not good practice to post non-answers as answers.  It's been a founding principle of the site that we want to have focused, clear questions, with correct, quality, specific answers.  The whole goal of the site was to move away from the model that forums encouraged with unclear questions, and a random assortment of information in response that may or may not have an answer in there somewhere, and even when there was correct information it wasn't found as it wasn't associated with the question, etc.  The site explicitly *forbids* non-answers posted as answers.

Comment: We're not discussing non-answers though. I'm saying that if a user has a potential XY problem it's okay to post an answer to Y because future visitors will want Y (and the OP might). I posted an answer to Y and you're randomly calling it a nonanswer again. Clarify why?

Comment: @djechlin You're posting something that's not an answer to the question.  Not an answer, hence, a non-answer.  That's not even starting on the fact that you're just linking to another answer elsewhere, rather than posting an actual answer to the question.

Comment: I posted an answer. You can verify against http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. It covers this case surprisingly explicitly.

Comment: By the way, do you think the bot is always right? We've spent a lot of energy debating the merits of one post of mine, but I'd be surprised if you believe the bot is always right and the answerer (me in this case) is always wrong. I was more interested in drawing attention to the fact that the UX punishes answerers when the bot wins and the answerer really doesn't agree with the bot (and some of the the time the answerer is right). That's not addressed in this Q/A at all right now.

Comment: @djechlin So you're asserting that the bot is wrong by providing just one example, and the example  you've chosen shows the bot doing exactly the right thing.  If you want to assert that there's a problem with the bot, you're going to need to do something other than support the opposing point.

Comment: @djechlin It looks like you didn't read your own link.  You're right, it's quite explicit: "Answer the question - Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that"  Given that you're specifically saying you're not even *trying* to answer that question, you're pretty clearly not meeting that requirement.   "Write to the best of your ability" Posting an answer that you know is poor with the expectation of editing it later is clearly not meeting this requirement either.

Comment: The quote past the part you truncated is here: "– or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."

Comment: Is there any reason you stopped reading the section past the first 134 characters? I'm baffled as to how you could take *the half of the sentence* that hammered your point that I definitively showed is incorrect while acting in good faith.

Comment: @djechlin Your answer *isn't* saying "don't do that".  Additionally you didnt, "mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer."

Comment: @djechlin I didn't quote the whole thing because it didn't apply to your answer.  You weren't doing that.

Comment: Yes I did. "If you're not trying to roll your own." Eyeballs. Read.

Comment: @djechlin "Don't do that" and, "If you're not actually trying to do that' are two very different things.  You're not providing an alternative to the question, you're just *answering an entirely different question*.

Comment: Using a system builtin i.e. not rolling your own is an alternative to shuffling an array.

Comment: Would you mind updating at least the last part of your answer per our discussion? They're very inaccurate given that I posted a quality answer, which we've taken the time to establish.

Comment: @djechlin It would seem that virtually nobody agrees with your assertion of that.  You seem to be the only one who thinks that it's a quality answer.

Comment: I'm referring to our 40+ comment analysis, not a popular vote. Much of the popular vote is looking to your analysis anyway. As the only person besides me who has thought about this a great deal, you have all the more reason to ensure your answer reflects your best understanding.

Comment: @djechlin So you're saying that you know what I think of the quality of your answer better than I do?  Since when have you been telepathic?  Given that you can apparently read minds, how is it that you still don't understand what the author of that question was actually asking when you posted your answer?  I mean, the fact that the question is (according to you) too unclear to know what it's asking apparently shouldn't stop you from reading his mind to know what he is actually asking.

Comment: We spent a lot of time establishing that I posted a quality answer. I addressed all your prior concerns including citations of SO help documentation. I don't see any concern you have remaining. This is the point where you normally would change your viewpoint. If you weren't willing to do this all along I'm not sure why you've been discussing.

Comment: @djechlin No, we did not establish that you posted a quality answer.  No, you did not address all of the concerns that I brought up with regards to your answer.  You've addressed *some* of the points I've raised asserting that your post *isn't an answer at all*.  I haven't even *begun* to discuss whether or not it's a *quality* answer, merely whether or not it is an answer that meets the minimum standard of being *an answer*.

Comment: Please review the "how to answer" link I shared above. It covers the content of my answer explicitly, as I've shown. If you dispute that that's fine, just show me the contradiction between my answer and "how to answer," but without quoting half a sentence where the other half proves your point incorrect like happened last time.

Comment: I still encourage you to make heavy edits to your answer regarding whether my post "passes the bar" so to speak. I was hoping to get to that but if you're not in the mood I'd still ask for you to remove this: "Can you treat others as adults, rather than **going out of your way to post low quality** content in a (apparently often unsuccessful) **attempt to earn more rep** by posting lower quality content? **Have some pride** in the quality of the content you post to the site" which I really feel is a personal attack. Emphasis mine obviously.

Comment: @djechlin If you're going to go out of your way to say that the system should be changed for preventing you from posting low quality content that you posted as a deliberate attempt to abuse the answering system, I'm going to call you out on it.  If you're going to not only take abusive actions, but claim that you shouldn't' be subject to the negative consequences of those actions, then you shouldn't expect people to not draw attention to that.

Comment: I'm sorry, low quality content? Likewise, if *you're* going to call someone out in insulting language, I'm going to call you out and make sure you get your facts straight or explain your point of view, which you haven't, despite my repeatedly showing you the same material proving you wrong, which you haven't acknowledged. It would be appreciated if you demonstrated any willingness to change your view.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I think that this whole auto-conversion thing should be scrapped entirely. Even some of the CMs agree it's stupid and not worth keeping around. [It also allows users without commenting privs to bypass the restriction.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233960/trivial-answer-converted-to-comment-should-not-bypass-the-50-rep-restriction) The FGITW problem described here can easily be solved by having people cast downvotes as prematurely as the answer itself — that's what I already do.

The 60-second rate limit is a separate thing that applies to *all* users, including mods (because mods don't need any special provisions for answering questions anyway). It is there to block flood requests. The fact is that you submitted an answer — regardless of whether that submission was accepted or rejected the server has every right to throttle your next answer submission for its own sanity.

Comment: You can not post the comment for users with less than 50 rep, if that's what you're worried about.  I've yet to see a quality answer converted to a comment with this system.

Comment: @Servy: It's not that quality answers are being converted to comments - it's that the system really isn't producing any worthwhile comments anyway. If we keep this thing I'd much rather it reject the submission altogether (with an error message) instead of trying to shoehorn it in the form of a comment (and not even do a good job of it - it doesn't even bother translating `[link][1] [1]: ...` to `[link](...)` for example).

Comment: Like I said, I've never seen a quality answer converted to a comment.  As far as rejecting the submissions altogether (possibly saying in the error message that they should consider posting the content as a comment) I'd be okay with that.